# show list of js file into php array list

Tags: php, arrays

I have this function for show list of `.js` file in bottom of page.

```
function load_js($js, $file = '')
{
    global $_admin_js;
    if ($file != '') {
        $file = preg_replace('/\\\/', '/', dirname($file));
    }
    $_admin_js [] = array(
        $js,
        $file
    );
}
```

add js file(ie page.php):

```
global $_admin_js;
load_js('admin/templates/js/jquery.icheck.min.js');
load_js('admin/templates/js/select2.js');
```

for result:

```
global $_admin_js;
    $value = '';
    foreach ( $_admin_js as $js ) {
        echo $js[0];
    }
```

and result is: `admin/templates/js/jquery.icheck.min.js`  `admin/templates/js/select2.js`

this worked but i need to print result in PHP `array` like this :

```
$exclude = array( 
    'admin/templates/js/jquery.icheck.min.js',
    'admin/templates/js/select2.js' 
);
```

How do show result in php `array` list?!

Comment: Just add it to an array variable: `$myArr = array(); $myArr[] = "item1"; $myArr[] = "item2"; $myArr[] = "item3"; ....`

Answer (score 0):

Almost there, just need to push the values into an array.

```
$exclude = []; 
foreach ($_admin_js as $js ) {
    $exclude[]= $js[0];
}
```

This should give you the results you want.

Comment: `print_r($exclude)` : result: `Array
(
    [0] => admin/templates/js/jquery.easypiechart.min.js
    [1] => admin/templates/js/chart.min.js
)`

Comment: @user27133 so, is not that what you wanted?

Comment: i need to this : `$exclude = array( 
    'admin/templates/js/jquery.icheck.min.js',
    'admin/templates/js/select2.js' 
);`